# BibLaTeX: How to create \NewDocumentCommand for automated Prenotes?

Tags: biblatex, citing

**Description:**

I am using a small modification to automatically add the abbreviation "cf." into citation prenotes:

```
\renewbibmacro*{prenote}{%
    \iffieldundef{prenote}%
    {% true
        \printtext{cf\adddot}%
    }{% false
        \printfield{prenote}}%
    \setunit{\prenotedelim}%
}%
```

Always adding "cf." is mostly useful, but not in every case. Therefore I want to outsource this auto-prenote into a separate `\NewDocumentCommand`. Only when typing `\cf-cite` or `\cf-autocite` the abbreviation should be added as a prenote.

How can I introduce that?

---

**Minimum Working Example (MWE):**

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}  
    @book{Doe,author = {Doe, Jon},date = {1998}}
\end{filecontents}

% ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[backend=biber,citestyle=numeric,style=authoryear,natbib=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\renewbibmacro*{prenote}{%
    \iffieldundef{prenote}%
    {% true
        \printtext{cf\adddot}%
    }{% false
        \printfield{prenote}}%
    \setunit{\prenotedelim}%
}%

\bibliography{\jobname}

\begin{document}

    This is a very simple example to demonstrate citing with auto-added prenotes \autocite[25]{Doe}.

    \par\bigskip As you can see, the abbreviation \enquote{cf.} will always be displayed. It is not possible to keep this field empty anymore. However, this is not useful in every case. Therefore I want to generate two \textbackslash NewDocumentCommand's:

    \begin{itemize}
        \item \textbackslash cf-cite and
        \item \textbackslash cf-autocite
    \end{itemize}

    Only when using one of those two new commands, the previous mentioned \enquote{cf.} should be displayed as a prenote. In all other cases the field should remain empty.

    \par\bigskip How can I do that?

\end{document}
```

---

**Edit:** When thinking about my previous idea that does not make big sense anymore. It does not matter if I have to write `\autocite[cf.][35]{Doe}` or `\cf-autocite[35]{Doe}`. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not exactly what you asked for, but I think it is an improvement on your attempt. I do think having the prenote built in is a little over, but to have your own "outsourced" prenotes as you suggested would require quite some structure with `\DeclareCitationCommand` for each variant of the several `biblatex` commands available for which you'd want this facility.

I think your original structure would work quite well in practice, and it is easy to disable the automatic insertion of "cf." with a simple toggle.

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
  @book{Doe,author = {Doe, Jon},date = {1998}}
\end{filecontents}

% ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[backend=biber,citestyle=numeric,style=authoryear,natbib=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\newtoggle{nocf}
\newcommand*{\nocf}{\AtNextCite{\toggletrue{nocf}}}

\renewbibmacro*{prenote}{%
  \iffieldundef{prenote}%
  {% true
    \iftoggle{nocf}{}{%
      \printtext{cf\adddot}%
    }%
  }{% false
    \printfield{prenote}%
  }%
  \setunit{\prenotedelim}%
}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

This is a very simple example to demonstrate citing with auto-added prenotes
\autocite[25]{Doe}.

\bigskip
As you can see, the abbreviation “cf.” will be displayed by
default. But it is possible to leave it empty with
‘\verb|\nocf|’ \nocf\autocite[34]{Doe}.

\bigskip
However, without it, the default behavior is back \autocite[29]{Doe}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: A cheap way to get a `\nocfautocite` that way is with `\newcommand*{\nocfautocite}{\nocf\autocite}`. (Though I think the logic was exactly the other way round in the question.)

Comment: @moewe I know, as I said "this is not exactly what you asked for"...

Comment: @moewe Btw, I'm gonna get a printscreen of this comment of yours before it vanishes. You suggesting a definition of a citation command with `\newcommand`! I thought that was banned by the Gospel!   ;-)

Comment: Ah. I thought the 'not exactly what you asked for' referred to not defining a command, but using a prefix command instead. I must say that I prefer the *`\autocite` gives no "cf.", `\cfautocite` gives "cf."* rule, but as the OP realised themselves, that almost makes the exercise pointless. As to `\newcommand` for `\cite` commands: There are some situations like this (and the ones in `blx-natbib.def`) where it does make sense: Things only become problematic when people try to combine several (proto-)`\cite` commands in one. (But of course you know that...)

Comment: @moewe Yes I'd simply go myself with `\autocite[cf.][23]{Doe}`. I also said I thought that the attempt was "over", but I didn't think of emphasizing that much, cause we all know: it's part of the fun too. As to `\newcommand` I get why it's safe here, of course, but I wouldn't miss the pun, would I?